# Zend Server 5.6 Community Edition has Expired in 2014. Can it still be renewed?

Tags: zend-server

My system is a 3-year-old legacy web app server. It is working fine at the moment.

Today, I got a ghost system error. I wanted to use the local Zend Server admin web to analyze it. But, I found it expired one month ago.

I have tried to get another trial (Community Edition) license to activate Zend Server.  But I found there's no more Community Edition license request on the official web page!

Is there any other way to get Community Edition License for Zend Server 5.6?

Answer (score 3):

I found this when digging through some email:

> Developer Edition Replaces Free Edition [...]
>
> Get your Free Upgrade to Zend Server 7 Developer Edition:   If you have
>   a license for Zend Server Free Edition, you will receive a free
>   license for Zend Server 7 Developer Edition.

http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/free-edition-upgrade

If that doesn't work, the developer edition is now ~$240 a year (per user though...).

Comment: A case of FOSS users being shafted again.